# How to get the current running office instance version number using VBA?

Tags: vba, office-interop, office-addins

I am developing Microsoft Office Add-in, I have to read the registry values of the current instance of the office in which my add-in will run.

Is there any way I can get the current office version number of add-in instance?

I have searched and found [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-vba-to-return-the-current-version-number-of-any-office-application/) solution. But it's is not working.

Thanks if anyone from you can help.

Comment: What is not working with `Application.Version` ? I get 14.0 for Office 2010 and 16.0 for 2016

Comment: @FunThomas what if I want to use my same add-in with word , excel and powerpoint etc?

Comment: `Application.Version` should work in all the office applications...?

Comment: Use reflection or a dynamic variable to call the function name. That way, you don't need to cast it to a specific Application object